# jquery Image slider navigation dots won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-slider

I've been trying to create a jQuery image slider. So far, I managed to get the image slider animate and slide when clicking buttons forward/backward. Now, I'm trying to create navigation dots. so far I've been successful in trying to slide them through animation/clicking on button forward/backward. but when I try clicking the dots so that the active slide shows up, it won't work. Here is my work (I'm not putting the whole code just the function that implements when you click on dot)

Here is the code:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGmRkR

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  sliderEvents();

});
var slides = $("#carousel .slides .slide")
var dots = $(".indicators .circle");

function sliderEvents() {

  dots.click(function() {

    var indeX = $(this).index();
    var currentSlide = slides.eq(indeX);
    currentSlide.addClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('blip');

    currentSlide.prev().removeClass('active');
    $(this).prev().removeClass('blip');
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  background: black;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 1.5em;
  color: white;
}
#carousel {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 45%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
.sliderbuttons {} #prev,
#next {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 148, 41, 0.68);
  box-shadow: 2px white;
  border: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* font-family: 'Baloo Tamma', cursive;
    */
  padding: 10px;
  top: 15%;
  width: 10%;
  /*making the prev,next on top of content*/
  z-index: 2;
}
#prev {
  left: 0;
}
#next {
  right: 0;
}
.active {
  z-index: 1;
}
.indicators {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 49%;
  left: 45%;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.indicators div {
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.blip {
  background-color: orange;
}
div.indicators:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Image carousel</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="carouselcss.css">
  <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Tamma" rel="stylesheet"> -->

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      header is here
    </header>
    <div id="carousel">
      <div class="sliderbuttons">
        <input type="button" name="next" id="next" value="&gt;">
        <input type="button" name="next" id="prev" value="&lt;">
      </div>
      <div class="slides">
        <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/4-Nature-Wallpapers-2014-1_ukaavUI.jpg" alt="image1" class="slide active">
        <img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/green-Rice-1600x900.jpg" alt="image2" class="slide">
        <img src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/nature-wallpapers-10.jpg" alt="image3" class="slide">

      </div>
      <div class="indicators">
        <div class="circle blip"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div>


    </div>

  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="carousel.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! The dots work for one set. like if you click on circle 1, slide 1 shows up. but when reclick circle 1, the slides doesn't show up. I'm not sure how I link circles to slides. I'm new to javascript/jquery

Comment: Can you please fix your jsfiddle so I can help? It's not working for me (images do not change on click)

Comment: jsfiddle appears to be missing some jquery library. I've put the code on here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGmRkR it should be working

Comment: That's weird. It works for me. Can you see the dots? have you tried to click on them?

Comment: I see, but it's not clickable. Try this https://jsfiddle.net/6qntgg5z/10/, I tried to blindly fix it. The idea is to remove the **blip and active** classes of the hidden slides.

Comment: Just to check, have you tried the codepen.io site I linked? (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGmRkR) and no I've put your solution and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had to remove the **blip and active** classes from each element, so they don't stack on top of each other. 
Here you go: http://codepen.io/denea/pen/wzdmoY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
sliderEvents();
//startSlider();

});

var slides = $("#carousel .slides .slide");
var dots=$(".indicators .circle");

function sliderEvents() {

dots.click(function () {

var indeX=$(this).index();
//console.log(indeX);
var currentSlide=slides.eq(indeX);
currentSlide.addClass('active');
$(this).addClass('blip');  

    $(".slides img").not(currentSlide).removeClass('active');
    $(".circle").not(this).removeClass('blip');
//console.log(currentSlide.prev().index());
});
}
```

Comment: It worked! thank you :) and yes, that's what I've been trying to do (remove class blip and active from the previously clicked elements) but I didn't know the right syntax.

Comment: Great, you could mark it as a solution in case it helped you.